# Is it Possible to Create a Custom Web Part that Embeds Performance Point Dashboards?

Tags: web-part, performancepoint

We are using PerformancePoint 2010 and have a number of dashboards setup already.  However, we don't like the look and feel of the filters rendered in the typical PeformancePoint view.  We instead would like to create a custom web part that hooks into PeformancePoint to retrieve the dashboards, but allows us to customize the UI a bit further.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the UI elements rendered by PerformancePoint can be styled with CSS.

This is probably more supportable and sustainable in the long run. Is there any reason CSS would not be an option?

Comment: Good point.  Where are the relevant CSS files located for PerformancePoint?

Comment: Don't bother editing them, create your own and override the classes.